# How to declare a function in the scope of the browser?

Tags: javascript

a function can be declared in the scope of the `window`-object that is accessible in that particular tab of the browser. The syntax is as follows:

```
window.f1=function(){
    //statements...
}
```

But is there a way to declare the function in the scope of the browser so that the function is accessible through any tab open in the browser. I want a syntax equivalent to the following

```
browser.f1=function(){//browser is what I want.
    //statements...
}
```

Can anyone suggest me a possible way?

Comment: It would be possible to do this using a web browser extension such as a Greasemonkey script.

Comment: You can create an extension for that.

Comment: No I fear this is impossible because every tab is a completely own handle and environment instance. As "CD..", just said you can write a browser extension but every user needs the same browser and the same extension installed for this to work.

Comment: And in case I want it for my own browser? How to do it? Suggest me programmatically please, I mean about the extension you are telling about.

Comment: @RajeshPaul That depends on which web browser you're using. If you want it to work in any browser, you might need to rely on a cross-browser framework.

Comment: you can use storage events to fire functions among different tabs of the same site. you can set the storage item to a json of arguments to be passed and re-set the item with the result of the function.

Comment: Those are nothing but hints for me. A sample code would be best.

Comment: @RajeshPaul Try doing a few Google searches based on the hints you've received: you might find what you're looking for.

Comment: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devguide.html

Comment: Thanx everyone for your response and navigating me in the right direction.

Comment: @RajeshPaul Just curious, what application you want to do with that?

Comment: If that was possible, a dubious banner in an arbitrary site could inject code into your online banking tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanx to the comments received on my question, I achieved it using `localStorege`. A quite fair reference is [**http://dev.w3.org/**](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/).

### code

```
<script>
    if(!localStorage.a)
    localStorage.a=10;
</script>
```

If this script is included in a webpage of a particular domain(say www.example.com). Then whenever that page or any other page belonging to that doman is opened in the previously used browser, you can access it as `localStorage.a` which will be `10` in this case until and unless you explicitly delete `localStorage.a`.

This is probably the simplest and shortest and hence the best solution to my problem. Thanx to everyone for providing the relevant info.

Comment: I'm not familiar yet with localStorage. Can you really store functions in it?